# Event in dynamically populated html in alert in angular 4 is not working

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am displaying alert content dynamically using alert control.

Code :

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
           message: '<div class="dialogMask">'+
                     '<div class="memberItem">'+

                       '<div class="memberDetails">'+
                    '<span class="name">'+this.name+'</span>'+

                    '</div>'+
                 '<div class="userOptions"><span class="call" 
                  (click)="callMemberUsingDialer()"></span>'+

                 '</div>'+
                '</div>',

             buttons:[
              {

                   role:'cancel',
                   handler:()=>{
                         console.log('alert dismissed');
                  }
                   }
                     ]
                  })
```

callMemberUsingDialer() function is not executing when I select click event in the above dynamic html content in the alert controller.

Please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior in two ways:

1) generate component at the runtime(which is quite a complicated solution, I would avoid doing this);

2) update your `alertCtrl.create`. After you insert the markup, you need to run synchronous change detection and bind all events using elementRef.
You can create for example a list of tuples like [selector, event, listener] and use it later in `create()` method.

so:

```
create(options) {
    /* inserting markup here */
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    options.eventBindings.forEach(([selector, event, listener]) => {
        const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(selector)
        if(element) { 
            element.addEventListener(event, listener); 
        }
    }
}
```